# Implementation of SQL snapshot function in SQL Express 2012

Tags: sql-server, delphi, sql-server-2012-express

I try to create a SQL Server database snapshot (MSSQL EXPRESS 2012 SP #1)  from Delphi  (XE2) code. The code is executed without any problem  but actually no snapshot file is created

Code example :

....
    LoadStringfromFile(sqlFilename, sqlString);

```
sqlString := StringReplace(sqlString, 'db_snapshot_name', SnapshotName, []);
sqlString := StringReplace(sqlString, 'physical_file_name', SnapshotFolder, []);
sqlString := StringReplace(sqlString, 'logical_file_name', DatabaseName, []);
sqlString := StringReplace(sqlString, 'source_database_name', DatabaseName, []);

Memo1.Lines.Add(sqlString);  //  result see below .... 

ExecuteSQLQuery(sqlString);

SSStatusBar.SimpleText := ' run sql file done !  ';

end;

procedure TSnapShotForm.ExecuteSQLQuery(const sqlValue: string);
var
aSQLQuery: .....;
begin

  ///
  ///
aSQLQuery:=.......Create(self);

aSQLQuery.Active := false;

aSQLQuery.Connection := aConnection;

aSQLQuery.SQL.Add(sqlValue) ;

aSQLQuery.Active := true;

aSQLQuery.Free;

end;
```

the SQL Statement used with this text goes like this

```sql
     CREATE DATABASE test_ss
     ON (   NAME = 'test_evaluation', 
FILENAME = 'd:\test_ss')
     AS SNAPSHOT OF test_evaluation
```

Any good idea what is wrong here ?

Comment: You could use Connection.Execute(SQL); Does ist work in the MSSMS? Database Snapshot is not supported on Express Edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Database Snapshot is not supported on Express Edition

[Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx)